# Netbeans 7.3 misreports an "Unused assignment" hint

Tags: netbeans

Netbeans 7.3.1 IDE says that "The assigned value is never used" in the indicated line of the following program:

```
public class JavaTest {
    static int f() {
        return Math.random() < 0.9 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    static int g() {
        return Math.random() < 0.2 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ret;
        while ((ret = f()) == 0) {  // Unused assignment???
            ret = g();
            if (ret != 0)
                System.out.println(ret);
        }

        System.out.println(ret);
    }
}
```

I guess this is a bug in Netbeans, but can someone confirm if they have seen it before?

Comment: This is probably because you set the value for `ret` but you never use this value before setting it again, thus there is no difference between `while((ret = f()) == 0)` and `while(f() == 0)`.

Comment: You are correct that this is a bug, but the fact that this is fooling Netbeans and a couple of people here (myself included) should suggests using clearer code. I'd use a different variable for the return of each function.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Good point by madth3, although Netbeans is in error, it's tricky enough to fool several people as well as Netbeans, so I'll clarify it by using a different variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:
Excellent point and sorry I didn't see it earlier.  I agree with you now and I can confirm with your exact code in Eclipse Juno SR2 that there is no warning about unused assignment. Netbeans is in error!

Original:
Netbeans is correct... you immediately assign ret a new value after that line so you might as well just compare f() to 0 e.g. `while(f() == 0)`

Comment: I don't think this is case. You say I immediately assign ret a new value, but that only happens if f() returns 0. If f returns non-0, then I come out of the loop, and the value returned by f(), which is assigned to ret, is then printed before main() exits. Therefore it's not an unused assignment.